# Creating an Https connecion with Client Side Certificate from PKCS#10 with SpongyCastle

Tags: android, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, spongycastle

**The goal**

I'm working on implementing communication with Client-Certificate.

Step 1: Create a PKCS#10 request (CSR) and give it to the my server for signing. The server contacts passes the CSR to the CA, and the CA signs it, and returns a PKCS#7 (with the signed PKCS#10 and the CA's certificate).

Step 2: Create a PKCS#12, store it securely on the Android device

Step 3: Create SSL connection so that the client will be authenticated according to the certificate.

Now, Step 1 works perfectly using SpongyCastle 1.50.0.0, but I'm stuck on the other steps...
I'm currently getting an SSL-Handshake exception, but I got the feeling that I should re-think on my implementation.

**The question**

Does anyone know how to implement the flow? How to create and store whatever's needed for a client side certificate to work well with Android's SSLContext, and how to create such SSLContext?

**What I tried so far**

My first attempt was to use the [KeyChain](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html), but we'd like to avoid the user interaction as described there. My second attempt was to follow [Rich Freedman's steps](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/), but I don't know how to create a PKCS#12 from the PKCS#7 and the private key. For persistence, I went over [this post](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/04/serializing-deserializing-rsa-public-private-keys-generated-using-bouncy-castle-library), but (a) it's C#, (b) it's unencrypted and (c) I think that the android platform has a better keys persistence mechanism, one that I yet know nothing about. Lastly, [this code](http://chengzhuliulin.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/create-pkcs12-from-pem-private-key-file-and-pkcs7-certificate-in-java/) (for creating a PKCS12 from PEM and PKCS#7) didn't work as well, as I didn't know how to get a CER file and the rest of the things it needs.

Thanks!

Comment: hi, I am doing the same task and hanging with numerous chunks of codes, nothing completely guiding to implement,gone through many threads , can you help me with your experience regarding this particular issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe not the best code, but it works, it does not strictly answer all you questions but maybe you will find pieces you can use.

Your flow is good, I'm doing the almost the same thing.

I'm keeping my keys in dynamically created keystore. Additionaly i have keystore with trusted certificates created with openssl tool.

For communication I've used okHttp + retrofit

https://github.com/square/okhttp
https://github.com/square/retrofit

Generate `KeyPair`:

```
public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
    return keyPair;
}
```

Generate csr:

```
private static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateCSRFile(KeyPair keyPair) throws IOException, OperatorCreationException {
    String principal = "CN=company1, OU=company1, O=company1, C=GB";
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    AlgorithmIdentifier signatureAlgorithm = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder()
            .find("SHA1WITHRSA");
    AlgorithmIdentifier digestAlgorithm = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA-1");
    ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm, digestAlgorithm).build(privateKey);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(new X500Name(
            principal), keyPair.getPublic());
    ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(X509Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(true));
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(X509Extension.keyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.keyCertSign
            | KeyUsage.cRLSign));
    csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extensionsGenerator.generate());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = csrBuilder.build(signer);

    return csr;
}
```

Send csr (you may need to convert it to pem format), receive certificate .

Init keystore:

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in;
try {
    in = App.getInstance().getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename);
        try {
            store.load(in, password);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //create new keystore
        store.load(null, password);
    }
```

Init truststore:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = App.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
try {
    trustStore.load(in, trustorePassword);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Add key to keystore (make sure your private key, and certificate match, keystore won't throw exception if they don't, and with okHttp this can cause libssl crashes (only on devices with api below 4.1):

```
keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, password, new X509Certificate[]{certificate});
```

Create okHttpClient with its own `SSLContext`:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
KeyStore keyStore = App.getInstance().getKeyStoreUtil().getKeyStore();
KeyStore trustStore = App.getInstance().getKeyStoreUtil().getTrustStore();

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustStore);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);

SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslCtx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
client.setSslSocketFactory(sslCtx.getSocketFactory());
client.setHostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

Look at Nikolay Elenkov blog, you can find many usefull informations with source code as well.

- http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/
- http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html
- http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html
- http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html
- http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html
- http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html

@edit

Post your exception

@edit2

In your case you need to extract your `X509Certificate` from webservice response, store it in keystore with privatekey used for generating csr request and store CA cert in another keystore which will work as truststore. (It can be the same keystore, but it's not recommended).

Comment: First and foremost, +1. 
I tried **everything** you wrote, except:
1. I think I'm OK with the javax.HttpsURLConnection, and don't really need OkHttpClient.
2. Currently, I get some exception from "kmf.getKeyManagers()" (which is hidden because the code is in an AsyncResult :( )

Comment: 1. You can use javax.HttpsURLConnection it will work correctly. I had code with okHttp so i posted it. 2. Without exception/code I can't tell what is wrong.

Comment: It didn't work. I get a 403 from the server, which means that something doesn't work with the Client-Certificate. Besides that, your code was very helpful - so I'm marking this as an answer, Opened another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476591/debugging-client-certificate-not-working-from-android) for the more specific issue I'm having.